# How we send in response large amount of data over 2 millions records from mongo expres to node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have a post api in express that response a mongo collection data that has over 2 milions records how we have to send back in response . 
frontend : jquery ajax call
backend : express mongo node

Comment: Hello, your question is way to open ended for us to give any help... Have you tried something? Does it work with 100 records? If yes, show us what's the error when sending more records...

Comment: @Salketer for small records it works fine , and i get the error 
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 000000013F76ECF5
 2: 000000013F7481A6
 3: 000000013F748BB0


And it crash my node aplication

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because you are using more memory than you have. That's happens because you seem to be loading the 2 million records in memory then trying to JSON them before sending.

You will need to stream the mongo records to the response, that way you will have only a subset of the collection at a time.

```
cursor.stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

JSONStream is a package that can help you do that very easily. Cursor would be your mongo cursor.

Read more about stream on the nodeJS docs to understand how it works. Basically you're receiving one document, stringify it, and send it out, rince and repeat.